# What is the name of this art deco style font?

Tags: fonts, art

Does any one know the name of this font? I've searched everywhere for it and can't seem to find an exact match. Many similar to it although not the same on some characters.

[image]

Comment: Just don't understand how the question could have been closed. It is hard to find more fully explained and straightforward question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is [Ano Half Wide](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/alias/ano/half-wide/) (or one of the other variants in this very large font family).

[image]